# Make Upcoming Events display in home page ReadOnly in SharePoint

Tags: view, events

I am new to SharePoint and I have added an Event view to my home page, as shown in the following image.

[image: Add Events View]

After adding it, I can see the upcoming events, but at the top of the view, there's a button to add a new event. I would like to know if there's a way of removing that button. Basically to show the upcoming events to the user without allowing him to create a new one.

[image: Event View]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the Edit (or higher) rights to the List named 'Events' -- set the user's rights to Read or View. You can find the list in Site Contents.

Comment: Thanks! that did it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. If I wanted to allow the users to create events from the calendar view but not from the screenshot in the question. Is there any way of disabling that "Add Event" button from the list of events but keep the user's rights to Edit?

Comment: There isn't as that is a system page you cannot modify.